# insert TYPO3 Fluid input type email

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

how do I get the type="email" via fluid on my input?

```
<f:form.textfield readonly="1" class="email" />
```

Output:

```
<input readonly="" class="email" type="text">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
<f:form.textfield type="email" readonly="1" class="email" />
```